# Unexplained Tap Gesture Behaviors

Tags: swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I am encountering two odd tap gesture behaviors that I cannot explain. First the code:

```
import Foundation

class Popover:NSObject {

private var image:UIImage!

private lazy var toastImageView:UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = self.image!
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    return imageView
}()

private lazy var dimView:UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.66)
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    return view
}()

func createToastWith(image:UIImage, onParent parentView:UIView, relativeToView:UIView) {

    self.image = image

    parentView.addSubview(dimView)
    parentView.addSubview(toastImageView)

    dimView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    dimView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    dimView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    dimView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    toastImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: relativeToView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    toastImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: relativeToView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    toastImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: relativeToView.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 4.0, options: .curveLinear , animations: {
        self.toastImageView.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {(isCompleted) in
        self.dimView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.toastImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}

@objc private func viewTapped() {
    print("TAPPED!")
    self.toastImageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

}

Issue #1: The tap gesture is not being recongized for `toastImageView`.

Issue #2: While the tap gesture IS being recongized for `dimView` it only works if the `UIView.animate` block is in play. If I remove that block, which I did as a test, the tap gesture doesn't work for the `dimView` either.

So the question is why the tap gesture doesn't work for `toastImageView` and why does the animate block HAVE to be there in order for it to work with `dimView`? When I say it doesn't work, I mean the `viewTapped` function is not called.

This class is called from a VC in the `viewDidDisplay` function. I also tried `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedLayout` to no effect.

**Update 1:** It seems the issue with the `toastImageView` is the alpha. I know you cannot have a tap on a hidden view but I guess this extends to a view also in the process of being hidden. So even in transition to alpha 0, it won't work. So this answers Issue #1. However, it does not answer issue #2 in terms of the requirement for the animation block.

**Update 2:** Earlier I thought I checked the dimmed view against calling it from a `Strong` vs. `Weak` position. I did not and only checked the image view which we now know was caused by the alpha transition. So the solution to the second issue, as Sh_Khan pointed out, was the weak nature of how the class was called.

Overall, while I understand why Apple does not allow touches on an item that is hidden (via alpha or otherwise) this is somewhat broken when dealing with animations where the hidden property (alpha) is in transition. Would be quite helpful to still allow a tap until it's actually gone from the screen.

Comment: Can you show where and when you instantiate PopOver it appears to be 100% that the reason is strong Vs Weak

Comment: You are correct. When I originally tested this with popOver as an instance variable and found it didn't work, I was likely checking against the tap of the image itself which later I found to be the result of the alpha animation. When you brought it up I unfortunately assumed I checked the background view as well. I did not. So indeed the animation requirement is due to strong/weak and the image tap is due to the alpha. I will note in my post above for posterity. I do wish there was a way to allow for a tap on this animated effect though...

Comment: you can add a transparent view above the imageView to simulate the tab while the imageView is fading

Comment: Agree, that is what I wound up doing. Kind of a hack way around something that should work directly. If it at least allowed the touches to pass through that would have worked as well. However, it's just in some weird in-between state where it cannot do anything but it's still technically there.